# Sphinx autocomplete search

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to do a google-style autocomplete search with sphinx and ajax.
Say user is looking for an iphone. The goal is that input like "ip", "iph", "ipho" must give me the result, but it does not, while "iphon" or "iphone" do.
So, what am i doing wrong here?

```
index product
{

        source = product


        path = /var/lib/sphinx/product



        docinfo = extern


        mlock = 0


        morphology = stem_enru


        min_word_len = 2


        charset_type = utf-8


        charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F

        min_prefix_len = 2

        max_substring_len = 6

        enable_star = 1


}
```

and the query

```
    $sphinx = new SphinxClient();`

    $sphinx -> SetLimits (0,1500,2500);

    $sphinx->SetServer('localhost', 9312);


    $sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);


    $sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);


    $sphinx->SetFieldWeights(array ('name' => 30, 'brand' => 20, 'parent_name' => 10, 'description' => 5));


    $result = $sphinx->Query($string, '*');
```

Comment: Firstly, morphology can have subtle side effects with a prefix index, you might find it best without. But main question, are you actully adding a 'star' to the end of the query. The query actully forwarded to sphinx should have the star, eg `iph*`

Comment: @barryhunter thanks! I added a * to the end and it worked. You should have posted it as answer